# How to find correct parameter FormData and Request headers in a python requests web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-imaging-library, python-3.8

I m trying to get data using requests web scraping from this web site https://enlinea.sunedu.gob.pe/verificainscripcion, the parameter is a doc in the example 06950413, and the captcha, also a hide parameter called _token, I got using xpath, so in the case of the captcha I get the image using xpath too and also I downloaded the image in a imagenes folder, after that I wait the captcha using the input() while I type the captcha letters in a captcha.txt, next I type the captcha i hit enter to continue but, I got a response json captcha error. this is my code:

```
from time import sleep
import requests
from lxml import html
from PIL import Image  # pip install Pillow
import io
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebkit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36",
    "Host": "enlinea.sunedu.gob.pe",
    "Origin": "https://enlinea.sunedu.gob.pe",
    "Referer": "https://enlinea.sunedu.gob.pe/verificainscripcion",
}
session = requests.Session()
login_form_url = 'https://enlinea.sunedu.gob.pe/verificainscripcion'
login_form_res = session.get(login_form_url, headers=headers)
sleep(5)
parser = html.fromstring(login_form_res.text)
special_token = parser.xpath('//input[@name="_token"]/@value')
print('token:', special_token[0])
span_image = parser.xpath('//div[@class="pull-right"]/span[@id="captchaImgPriv"]/img')[0].get("src")
print(span_image)
image_content = requests.get(span_image).content
image_file = io.BytesIO(image_content)
image = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB')
file_path = './imagenes/captcha.jpg'
with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
    image.save(f, "JPEG", quality=85)
input()
login_url = 'https://enlinea.sunedu.gob.pe/consulta'
login_data = {
    "doc": "06950413",
    "opcion": 'PUB',
    "_token": special_token[0],
    "icono": '',
    "captcha": open('captcha.txt').readline().strip()
}
print(login_data)
rep = session.post(
    login_url,
    data=login_data,
    headers=headers
)
print(rep.text)
```

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that you didn't use the session when you built the captcha image request. Requesting the image gives a cookie that should be sent back with the form :

The following script use beautifulsoup instead of xpath/lxml, download the captcha, shows the captcha, waits for user input and gets the data :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PIL import Image 
import io
import json 

host = "https://enlinea.sunedu.gob.pe"
doc = "06950413"

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get(f"{host}/verificainscripcion")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

payload = dict([
    (t["name"],t.get("value","")) 
    for t in soup.find("form", {"id": "consultaForm"}).find_all("input")
])
payload["doc"] = doc

image_content = s.get(f'{host}/simplecaptcha').content
image_file = io.BytesIO(image_content)
image = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB')
image.show() 

captcha = input("please enter captcha : ")
payload["captcha"] = captcha

print(payload)
r = s.post("https://enlinea.sunedu.gob.pe/consulta", data = payload)

data = json.loads(r.text)
print(data)
```

output :

```
please enter captcha : YLthP
{'doc': '06950413', 'opcion': 'PUB', '_token': 'gfgUTJrqPcmM9lyFHqW0u5aOdoF4gNSJm60kUNRu', 'icono': '', 'nombre': '', 'captcha': 'YLthP'}
[{"ID":"1519729","NOMBRE":"OSORIO DELGADILLO, FLOR DE MARIA","DOC_IDENT":"DNI 06950413","GRADO":"<b>BACHILLER EN EDUCACION ","TITULO_REV":"<b>BACHILLER EN EDUCACION","GRADO_REV":null,"DIPL_FEC":"26\/06\/1987","RESO_FEC":"-","ESSUNEDU":"0","UNIV":"UNIVERSIDAD INCA GARCILASO DE LA VEGA ASOCIACI\u00d3N CIVIL","PAIS":"PERU","COMENTARIO":"-","TIPO":"N","TIPO_GRADO":"B","DIPL_TIP_EMI":null,"TIPO_INSCRI":null,"NUM_DIPL_REVA":null,"NUM_ORD_PAG":null,"V_ORIGEN":null,"NRO_RESOLUCION_NULIDAD":null,"FLG_RESOLUCION_NULIDAD":null,"FECHA_RESOLUCION_NULIDAD":null,"MODALIDAD_ESTUDIO":"-"}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bertrand Martel, however I got a little problem with {now.strftime("%s")[:-3]}') ValueError: Invalid format string. So I realized that deleting from ?date=, It was a distractorr I think so. I mean changing like this image_content = s.get(f'{host}/simplecaptcha').content worked. Thanks.

Comment: @GSandro_Strongs strange it must be strftime format issue, but you're right I think the `date` parameter is for caching and not useful in the context of scraping. I've updated the answer